# Build with /MT crashes on std::cout variable initialization in Release, but not in Debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have a Visual Studio 2015 application which links against two static libs (in the same solution) and some Qt libs (dynamic).

The application and each static lib are built with /MT. Everything runs fine with the Debug build, but the release build crashes at startup on dynamic initialization of '*std::cout*' static variable (called from *_initterm*). I cannot deep further because I miss the debug symbols of deeper calls...

I suspect either :

- static initialization fiasco somewhere between my static libraries and the VC runtime static libraries...
- Qt which might be built with /MD and create conflicts, but here also, I cannot be sure without debug informations...

Does anyone have an idea why ? Or some tips to debug this ?

**Edit :**

I tried without Qt, with only the two static libs linked to an application, the std::cout dynamic initialization is OK (_initterm ends without issues), but then, once entered in the main, when I try to instanciate and then destroy a std::istringstream, it crashes in the virtual destructor of std::istringstream... I don't get it...

Comment: Was Qt built with Visual Studio 2015? Are you mixing Debug and Release?

Comment: have you tried running debug build through valgrind or some bounds checker? the possible scenario if your program is not very carefull with array bounds the debug info is getting corrupted silently, but when you build release more valuable data is getting smashed thus the difference.

Comment: @drescherjm : Yes Qt was built with Visual Studio 2015. No I'm not mixing Debug and Release builds. I use Qt5 CMake to do the job for me :) I have no problem when I build everything as DLL and /MD. The weird thing here is that the issue happens in Release and not in Debug.

Comment: @tohaz : No i haven't but you gave me the idea to try with application verifier, it might notify me about things going wrong. Concerning initialization difference or array overflow, i doubt because it's really at early startup, my own dynamic initializer code is not even called yet.

Comment: Follow [these instructions](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC) carefully.  And do *not* ignore "I will not recommend you use it, because it can cause runtime errors, etc"

Comment: Thank you for this link, but I have errors even without Qt, I've just tried with a single static lib linked to my exe now, and it crashes in an std::istringstream inside the static lib code. It might be related to template instanciations trying to share code at the final link. The question is why these share codes end up to be different/incompatibles. Indeed both static lib and executable are compiled with /MT... I will do a full project comparison to see if some options might cause this incompatibility